# LINQ Query for outerjoining Parent and child (nested) tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have three levels of tables "Directors", "Managers" and "Leaders" with one to many relationship between them.

I would like to bring All the rows from Directors, Managers and Leaders separately along with their children relationship.(maybe LeftOuterJoin)

For example Directors table have

## DirectorID  DirectorName

```
     1            Director1
```

Managers

## Manager ID Director ID Manager Name

```
  1              1                 Manager 1
  2              1                 Manager 2
```

Leaders

## Leader ID Manager ID Leader Name

```
  1                 1              Leader 1  
  2                 1              Leader 2
```

I want the query to return

## DirID DirectorName MgrID ManagerName LdrID LeaderName

1             Director1
1             Director1      1        Manager1
1          Director1      1        Manager1     1       Leader1
1          Director1      1        Manager1     2       Leader1
1          Director1      2        Manager2

My linq query only results 3 rows

## DirID DirectorName MgrID ManagerName LdrID LeaderName

1          Director1      1        Manager1     1       Leader1
1          Director1      1        Manager1     2       Leader1
1          Director1      2        Manager2

```
             var query = from d in db.Directors
                        join m in db.Managers on d.DirectorID equals m.DirectorID into directorMgrGroup
                        from dmgr in directorMgrGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join l in db.Leaders on dmgr.ManagerID equals l.ManagerID into mgrLeaderGroup
                        from mlgr in mgrLeaderGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

It feels like a small tweak. just can't get it right. can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please include the `select` clause. Also what's the expected result type - `IQueryable<anonymous type>` or could be for instance `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`? I'm asking because joins are not problem, but the sample output cannot be produced with LINQ to Entities, but eventually can with LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Thank you. I mistakenly forgot to add it in the above sql. but i do have a select new {} in my linq query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It feels like a small tweak

Well, not exactly. The result format in SQL is produced by so called `ROLLUP` query which is not supported natively by LINQ. [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) will gather the information needed, but flattening it the way you want is quite hard as you may see below (combinations of singe item array concatenating the group join groups). Check it out:

```
var query =
db.Directors.GroupJoin(db.Managers, director => director.DirectorId, manager => manager.DirectorId, (director, managerGroup) => new
{
    Id = director.DirectorID,
    Name = director.DirectorName,
    Managers = managerGroup.GroupJoin(db.Leaders, manager => manager.ManagerId, leader => leader.ManagerID, (manager, leaderGroup) => new
    {
        Id = manager.ManagerID,
        Name = manager.ManagerName,
        Leaders = leaderGroup.Select(leader => new
        {
            Id = leader.LeaderID,
            Name = leader.LeaderName
        })
    })
})
.SelectMany(director =>  
    new[] { new
    {
        DirID = director.Id, DirectorName = director.Name,
        MgrID = (int?)null, ManagerName = (string)null,
        LdrID = (int?)null, LeaderName = (string)null
    } }
    .Concat(director.Managers.SelectMany(manager => 
        new[] { new
        {
            DirID = director.Id, DirectorName = director.Name,
            MgrID = (int?)manager.Id, ManagerName = manager.Name,
            LdrID = (int?)null, LeaderName = (string)null
        } }
        .Concat(manager.Leaders.Select(leader => new
        {
            DirID = director.Id, DirectorName = director.Name,
            MgrID = (int?)manager.Id, ManagerName = manager.Name,
            LdrID = (int?)leader.Id, LeaderName = leader.Name
        }))
    ))
);
```

Comment: It is indeed complex. I made it work to my situation. But I am still wrapping my mind around logic. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to write a SQL query, put it into a sql View and map it as an EF entity. This way you get this exeuced in the DB (it's still the fastest to run) and can still  filter it in EF.

outer joins are always a pain in the ass with EF

```
Create View ViewMyShiningAss
Begin
 /* select the outer join shit */
end
```

Update the EF model

```
using(var ctx = new MyModelEntities())
{
    var x = ctx.ViewMyShiningAss.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why is this an answer -- this sounds like "I don't know how to do this so I suggest you do something else."  If you don't know how to do something don't answer the question.

Comment: I agree with the SQL query suggestion, I also agree that this should be a comment

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. thank you. i tried left join and left outer join. it is still the same. do i need to create two querys and have an union in between them?

Comment: @Hogan Sometimes an answer is a concept, sometimes a piece of code, and sometimes it's just pointing the person into the right direction and preventing him from going down the wrong one. If you do not know the difference between this, ... than you should not give such genious commments

Comment: you need a left join => Directors left join Manager left join Leader

Comment: be sure you are not filtering it out in the where clause

Comment: Left join doesn't bring the results i need. I want all the records from "Directors" table + the matched records from "Managers" table (the complete rows by themselves) + additional rows from "Leaders" table if there are any matching records. I feel like i need a union of some sort.

Comment: @Lavanya what you are describing is a left join.

Comment: @user853710 you have amused me with your spelling fail.

Comment: @Hogan you can frustate youself , and exchange the view with a kiss

Comment: @lavanja you are describing a left join.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
check your data and relations.